# 2006 error code mapping for migrating from mysqli to PDO

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I'm converting a PHP code, which uses mysqli for connecting to mysql database, to a PHP code that uses PDO for connecting to mysql database.

Is there a [SQLSTATE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15817_01/appdev.111/b31228/appd.htm) which is equivalent to the error code [2006](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-client.html#error_cr_server_gone_error) in mysqli?

Because a piece of my code is written like this:

```
switch($this->_dbi->errno){
    case 2006:
        $this->close();
        throw new Exception();
        break;
}
```

How can I use PDO to rewrite this code?

*SQLSTATE* is the return value of [PDO::errorCode](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorcode.php).

Error 2006(CR_SERVER_GONE_ERROR) means *MySQL server has gone away*

Comment: Try [`PDO::errorInfo`](http://php.net/manual/pdo.errorinfo.php) instead, element #1 - *"Driver specific error code"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the array of [`PDO::errorInfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php). There you get an array like the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => HY000
    [1] => 1
    [2] => near "bogus": syntax error
)
```

- **0:** This is the same value like on [`PDO::errorCode`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorcode.php).
- **1:** The error number. Different between the database providers, but here would be your error number 2006.
- **2:** The error message / description.

**Your example would look like this:**

```
switch ($pdo->errorInfo()[1]) {
    case 2006:
        $this->close();
        throw new Exception();
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :-)